# How to filter the subscribed contracts events with their topics?

Tags: ink, events

I need to subscribe to my smart-contract events (`#[ink(event)]`). So I `state_subscribeStorage` to "System.Events" storage key. But then I get all system events of all smart contracts in my chain. Can I save websocket traffic and have only events that I am interested in?

Since substrate contract events have topics (`#[ink(topic)]`), there has to be a way to filter the received events by the topics. Or else why are the topics introduced?

I know about [external indexers](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-there-a-good-indexer-for-substrate-chains-like-the-graph). But I would like to be simple and use only the substrate node.

Comment: maybe search for `storage_changes` in the Substrate codebase

Answer (score 2):

You can use [useink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/useink) and the hook [useEvents](https://github.com/paritytech/useink/blob/main/packages/useink/src/react/hooks/contracts/useEvents.ts), which will subscribe to a contract's events. [Here is an example](https://github.com/paritytech/useink/blob/f93af9a52ced6583729b594ff7af58865deb2ab7/playground/src/components/pg-deploy/DeployPage.tsx#L303) using it and decoding the events that are emitted.