# Get account transactions using Substrate API

Tags: account, transactions, python

I think Substrate API is really messy and difficult to understand. How could I get all the transactions for an account? And getting account by address is also counterintuitive: you need to make a `query` with some module and function but I didn't find any list of available functions and modules. So I would appreciate if you could suggest me clear and full documentation.

P.S. I'm using `Python` for development, so therefor I use [py-substrate-interface](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface) and code for getting account by address looks like:

```
result = substrate.query(
    module='System',
    storage_function='Account',
    params=['F4xQKRUagnSGjFqafyhajLs94e7Vvzvr8ebwYJceKpr8R7T']
)
```

Comment: Need tutorial for Golang also

Comment: In case, I found partial docs for [polkascan](https://explorer.polkascan.io/polkadot/runtime/polkadot-9170) with all historical pallets, but still there's nothing about getting full list of extrinsics for an account

Comment: If you want to query across history then you might be after an indexer for speed: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-there-a-good-indexer-for-substrate-chains-like-the-graph

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Substrate indeed covers quite many use-cases, not just transferring coins from one account to another, and some of that complexity will leak through any API, even if there are specialized ones in the making for a few typical use-cases.

The part of the system you care about in your question is the `Balances` pallet that has a pretty comprehensive [Rust documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/pallet_balances/index.html). This pallet does not maintain a list of extrinsics that changed the balance of the account, but [some nodes in the network](https://polkadot.subscan.io/account/12zsKEDVcHpKEWb99iFt3xrTCQQXZMu477nJQsTBBrof5k2h?tab=transfer) index `Transfer` events while executing blocks and store these events in a database. You can also build such a node on your own, [this answer to another question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/56/138) might help you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check Rust docs. But how could I get this aggregated data, is requesting some 3d-party services the only chance?

Comment: I edit and add link to another question that answers how you can build your own indexing node.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

No blockchain is designed to be able to easily get all transactions for an account, as this is a waste of storage for a normal syncing chain.

Substrate provide the ability to run an Archive node, which stores all state for all blocks since the genesis, but querying for all transactions for a user would require searching all blocks, which can be slow for sure.

The correct solution for such a query is to use a blockchain indexer as described here: [Is there a good indexer for substrate chains (like the graph)?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-there-a-good-indexer-for-substrate-chains-like-the-graph)

Or a block explorer like:

- https://polkascan.io/
- https://www.subscan.io/