# Get Transactions from wallet address in polkadot.js/api

Tags: polkadot-js, transactions

I want to know how I can get list of transactions and transactions info for specific wallet address in polkadot.js/api, especially for kusama.

```
const provider = new WsProvider("wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io");
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });
const response = await api.rpc.eth.getTransactionByHash(hash);
```

I am not sure if above code is for transactions, however it is not running and cause error.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: api.rpc.eth.getTransactionByHash is not a function
```

How can I get transactions from wallet address in polkadot.js/api?

Comment: Duplicate of https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/get-transaction-by-hash & https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/get-account-transactions-using-substrate-api

Comment: It doesn't give answer for my question. I commented in above question, how can I get transactions from block? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: I believe both links by @Jaco are answering your question: 

The node itself doesn't index all transactions, it just stores blocks and states. You should fetch all blocks yourself and index transactions.
If you want to fetch transactions from a block you can use API Sidecar to do this: Have a look at https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-node-interaction#fetching-a-block for more details

Answer (score 6):

To answer your comment around block-by-hash (there are no account -> transaction mappings on the RPCs, as per the linked answers in the comments above) -

You can use the [getBlock](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc#getblockhash-blockhash-signedblock) RPC call. Since you are using the JS API based on your example -

```js
// retrieve the block by hash, API decodes extrinsics
const signedBlock = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock("0x...blockHash here...")

// loop through extrinsics
for (let i = 0; i < signedBlock.block.extrinsics.length; i++) {
  const x = signedBlock.block.extrinsics[i];

  console.log(`
    isSigned=${x.isSigned},
    pallet=${x.method.section},
    method=${x.method.method}
  `)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to run your code. However, it doesn't give transaction information. Like transaction amount, type, fee etc. How can I get it?

Comment: Those are all part of the arguments - x.args in the naming above.