# What's the Substrate's equivalent of receipts in Ethereum?

Tags: extrinsic, events

I want to check if a given extrinsic is executed successfully or not from a light client inside the enclave (aka Intel SGX). I am importing new blocks, iterating over the extrinsics I am interested in, and taking actions based on that.

Extrinsics that fail are also included in that list, so what's the Substrate's equivalent of [receipts in Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16525/what-are-ethereum-transaction-receipts-and-what-are-they-used-for)?

Specifically, how to verify the events at a different point in time as we do in [Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16117/proving-the-existence-of-logs-to-the-blockchain)

Comment: Can you clarify for the unfamiliar what receipts area link to more info?

Comment: Looks like you already did :)

Answer (score 3):

Practically speaking, [events](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/events-and-errors/) are what you are looking for. It is up to the pallet implementation to define and emit these in a way that is useful for end consumers, like for use case.

If there is information missing in events that you're needing from a pallet, best to raise an issue to get specific about requirements to get those events baked in.

Comment: I know about Events, but my question is how we can verify an event's existence when we import a block at a later point in time since Substrate removes Events from storage the next block. In Ethereum, the receipts are also stored and can be retrieved to verify the status of a txn present inside a given block.

Comment: There are `trie_root` and `extrinsic_root` in substrate header but no `receipt_root` which used as proof of event or logs as you mentioned. But we you can extend [`digest_item`](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/enum.DigestItem.html) in header to add some proof which can be verified later

Comment: Are there any examples or references to this approach?

Comment: How can you store this: an indexer like [substrate archive](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive) is typically used.

Comment: See also https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-there-a-good-indexer-for-substrate-chains-like-the-graph

Comment: Thanks @DanShields but I need to verify events inside a light client, indexers are not useful for that.