# How do I find the gas consumed by a contracts extrinsic?

Tags: smart-contract, weight, pallet-contracts

I am querying extrinsic data and I am able to fetch `gasLimit` and `gasPrice` out of `Extrinsic.method.args`. But how do I fetch the amount of gas used from an extrinsic?

Comment: Hi, are you using contracts or pallets? Because gas is a contract specific terminology while pallets use weights to determine the cost of a transaction . Please do clarify

Comment: @islami00 it's a contract

Answer (score 3):

Gas and weight are one and the same concept when it comes to pallet-contracts. We merely kept the name gas for historic reasons. The gas limit you supply to the `contracts.call` extrinsic directly influences the weight of the extrinsic (1to1 translation).

So what you want to index is the `system.ExtrinsicSuccess` or `system.ExtrinsicFailed` event emitted by the `contracts.call` exrinsic. It contains a `weight` field which tells you the overall weight of the extrinsic. This is essentially the gas that was consumed + static overhead of the extrinsic.

I think things get clearer when you look at the [weight annotation of the `call` extrinsic](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/662598908902ec8879fcd6a950324ef6735ea1f6/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L358):

```rust
#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::call().saturating_add(*gas_limit))]
pub fn call() { ... }
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for the answer! is it the same in moonbeam too?

Answer (score 1):

[image: contractsCall]

*Click the image for better resolution*

With a contracts call extrinsic there will be an associated event `ExtrinsicSuccess` where you can deduce the [gas consumed](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/smart-contracts/#gas). You may want to look at using an [indexer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-there-a-good-indexer-for-substrate-chains-like-the-graph).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Polkadot API, you need to check the Contract section (https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/contract.read/):

```js
const { gasConsumed, result, output } = await contract.query.get(alicePair.address, { value, gasLimit });
```

Interacting with your contract (querying or executing functions) will return information like the gasConsumed in the execution, as shown above.

Comment: thing is, i'm not interacting with any contracts. I'm merely indexing the details of previous interactions on chain.