# How to subscribe to contract events using RPC?

Tags: ink, events

I'm looking to subscribe to events emitted from a contract.

I am currently creating a storage key for **System** **Events**, subscribing to it and filtering the events to get the one emitted by the contract I am interested in.

Is there a better way to subscribe to the events of a specific contract?

Comment: Did you work it out? I am also puzzled by this. I want to use the substrate node itself, not an external indexer (like here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-there-a-good-indexer-for-substrate-chains-like-the-graph).

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery [event handler](https://doc.subquery.network/build/mapping.html) to capture the desired events. It supports filtering based on `Modules` (the `contracts` module in this case) and `Methods`.

This filters all events of all contracts. But to filter the events for a specific contract, you'll have to [subscribe](https://doc.subquery.network/it/run_publish/subscription.html#filtering) to the contract's entity in the schema, and filter this subscription with the contract address

Comment: Thank you. But, I'm building a Go client and am currently working on extending this https://github.com/torusresearch/go-substrate-rpc-client for contracts.

Comment: I also tried to use `Contracts` as the module, it doesn't have the storage for `Events`

Comment: I'd use centrifuge rather than that fork as it looks like more dev is on centrifuge's original though I can't see ink support commits - maybe ask that question in that projects github issue asking for support?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include Centrifuge's repo there. That's our fork where we're working on extending it to support contracts.

But, my question is more related towards the RPC support in substrate itself. I mean, if substrate has something for it, I could use it irrespective of the library.